# When do I need submit my software by in order to be in the software center for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-center, application-development, repository

I am working on developing a program and want to put it in the software center when I am finished. Do I have to upload the program to developer.ubuntu before the release of 12.04 if I want it to be in the 12.04 software center? Or can I finish after the release and have it put in the repositories at that time?

Comment: @hhlp No, here I'm asking *when* should I get my software in, I already know *how*. Unrelated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may submit an application that runs on 12.04 anytime that 12.04 is a supported version of Ubuntu, which in this case is 5 years after release. When you upload an application you  should indicate what versions of Ubuntu you wish to support, supporting the current release and the LTS is suggested.

Depending on your application it can take a week to approve and publish, so to be in the software center for the release of 12.04 I would give us a little additional time as it does get busy.

Comment: So to clarify: If I finish my application and submit it after 12.04 is released, I can still get it in the 12.04 software center?

Comment: @William yes, as long as the 12.04 is supported.

Answer (score 3):

Go to http://developer.ubuntu.com/ to find how to get your software to the Ubuntu software center.
"Or can I finish after the release and have it put in the repositories at that time?"

I think it is hard if Ubuntu 12.04 is released. Then you cannot put you software into repositories of default Ubuntu software center. It is better if you finish your software earlier than the final release of Ubuntu! Hope this help you!

Comment: I have already registered the project on developer.ubuntu, do I need to register it on launchpad as well? Also, do you have a source for the fact that software cannot be added to the USC? Thanks.